# Intellij cant build JVM

Tags: intellij-idea, jvm

I can run java from command line, but when trying to run with Intellij I get this error msg.

```
Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: "-Xmx6144m"
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx6144m
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

Why is -Xmx6144m invalid?

It works fine in command line...

```
$>javac -version
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: "-Xmx6144m"
javac 1.8.0_71
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JDK configured for your project in IntelliJ IDEA is different from the one that is specified by the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable in your shell. You can open the Project Structure dialog and select the correct JDK for your project. (To use `-Xmx6144m`, it needs to be a 64-bit JDK.)